# Will this type of engine produce thrust?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, heat-engine

I was wondering that if we replace the combustion chambers in a jet engine with heaters heating the compressed air up to temperature near to plasma then what will be the case, will it produce any kind of thrust or it will be just useless

Comment: The basic principle is sound, i.e. it's just a jet engine but using an electric heater instead of combustion products as an energy source. I doubt it is feasible to make it efficient enough for practical use though. The cost, energy density and power output of jet fuel are the reasons it is used in aviation and not your device. :)

Comment: if exclude the eficiency term then is it posible to use one of them

Comment: It will generate thrust for sure, but probably far too little to be of practical use (I'd like to be proven wrong here!). The basic physics is fine; it's an engineering problem. So sure, if you ignore all the practical problems related to the energy density and power output and resulting thrust-to-weight ratio problems then the idea could work.

Comment: can you suggest me a page describing the condition's you mentioned here which would play a role in it's working and generate  thrust

Comment: The purpose of combustion in jet engines is to increase the enthalpy of the flow so that it can be accelerated through a nozzle (part of the energy is extracted by a turbine to power the compressor/propeller). The way you have drawn your diagram, all of the energy provided by the heater is expelled out the back and wasted.

Comment: what if it is heated near to plasma temp

Comment: Don't forget that you are using electricity to power this device, which is quite likely coming from a mechanical source. So why go through all the losses and efficiencies, while you can use your mechanical source directly. One more thing, the expanding gas in the jet engine powers *the turbine*, which causes expansion *and* it powers the compressor then the nozzle which increases the thrust. You don't have that here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the main idea behind [laser-driven heat exchanger propulsion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_propulsion#Heat_Exchanger_.28HX.29_Thruster):

> The laser beam heats a solid heat exchanger, which in turn heats an
>   inert liquid propellant, converting it to hot gas which is exhausted
>   through a conventional nozzle. This is similar in principle to nuclear
>   thermal and solar thermal propulsion. Using a large flat heat
>   exchanger allows the laser beam to shine directly on the heat
>   exchanger without focusing optics on the vehicle. The HX thruster has
>   the advantage of working equally well with any laser wavelength and
>   both CW and pulsed lasers, and of having an efficiency approaching
>   100%. The HX thruster is limited by the heat exchanger material and by
>   radiative losses to relatively low gas temperatures, typically 1000 -
>   2000 C, but with hydrogen propellant, that provides sufficient
>   specific impulse (600 – 800 seconds) to allow single stage vehicles to
>   reach low Earth orbit.

The [lightcraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightcraft) is another variation, but that doesn't rely on any fuel, it simply uses the shape of side mirrors to focus the laser into the surrounding air and provide thrust

[image: lightcraft]

Answer (score 2):

The problem here (as Michael mentioned) is, there's no relation between heat and thrust. In fact, compressing the mixture produces heat, which helps to ignite the fuel along with compressed air. The gases, occupying more volume is exhausted out through the nozzle which helps thrusting the aircraft.

Your engine doesn't produce any thrust at all. In your case, there's a *pumping* propeller. You're just heating the air flowing through the heater. At higher velocities, the effect is negligible. I can't think of higher velocities because the aircraft can get **no** thrust using an engine, where air flows in and out..!

You may argue that hot air expands. But, simply heating the air in an airflow won't push the heater to the front (it's very negligible to be noticed). As I've mentioned earlier, more volume is exhausted in an engine since liquid has changed into a gas mixture. Here, the same air comes out (i.e.) $V_{in}=V_{out}$ which doesn't do much good for an aircraft.

---

**Response based on Revision:** Again, the thrust doesn't depend on how much you heat the stuff inside. It does, but it's based on how much kinetic energy, the gas volume (sucked inside) obtains, so that the contribution by the outgoing gas lump (as a whole) corresponds to your thrust. Returning to your question, I think it's quite ambiguous.

- Firstly, as far as I know, no known chamber exists. Recall the phrase. The fuel sprinkled on the compressed "air lump" isn't just good enough to heat it to plasma.
- Even if you've managed to heat the thing somehow to attain plasma, I can bet bet you that the chamber will be able to hold it, as time goes on. As far as I can say, the material gets fried up..!!!
- There are other issues in holding plasma, as it's a giant bulk of ions. I don't wanna go into it, as I've come to the conclusion that such a thing is just fiction. The engine's gonna cease out for sure ;-)

Comment: Right. Electric heaters with fans draw air from behind and blow it ahead without running around the room :)

Comment: @annav: Hah... That's a nice example which can add-up to my answer ;-)

Comment: The thrust due to the extra fuel mass being expelled out the back is negligible. The majority of the thrust is due to converting enthalpy to kinetic energy by accelerating the flow through a nozzle. At least this is true for turbojet engines. Turbofan engines extract energy from the hot air aft of the combustor to power the fan which produces most of the thrust.

Comment: i have made kind of a lame and basic diagram with missing part but my point was that if we replace the combustion chambers in a jet engine with heaters heating the compressed air upto temperature near to plasma then what will be the case

Comment: @Akash: Well, you should've added that to your question. Because, your *point* isn't there in the question. In such a case, how can we interpret your *point* simply by seeing the figure you've drawn, which also doesn't state *"plasma, jet engine"*, etc.? o_O

Comment: yeah you are right i will edit it i was a little bit lame when asking it i will edit it

Comment: Your answer implies that it's the additional mass of the fuel that provides trust in a jet engine. While it's true that there is a tiny contribution due to increased mass flow going out, this is only a significant source of thrust for a rocket engine. Jet engines develop power/thrust through heating and expanding the air, just as the op proposed, though to a lesser extent. A jet engine whose "combustion chamber" was replaced with a electric heater would work just fine (assuming you could get the heating element to not melt at the temperatures required).

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between what you have and a jet engine is the incoming cold air needs to be compressed, so the heater expands pressurized air which thrusts out the back.
The thrust is because the momentum flux out the back (i.e. mass times velocity per second) is larger than the momentum flux in the front.

The mass per second is the same, front and back, but the velocity is higher at the back because it has been heated to a larger volume.
What keeps it from blowing out the front is the fact that the pressure is high coming out of the compressor.
Usually what drives the compressor is a small turbine that takes away a portion of the energy in the exhaust stream.

Anything that compresses the air in front will do the job. A [*ramjet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramjet) does it by simply using the ram pressure of air from the moving vehicle.

Comment: so if I compress the air before heating it will it work

Comment: @Akash: In principle, though your heater would have to pump out as much heat as a gas flame if you want to get noticeable thrust.

Comment: something like turning the intake near to plasma and then pump it out

Comment: @Akash: No need to get carried away :)  The [*J58-P4 engine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird#Engines) of the SR-71 generated about 16 tons of thrust, but there's no mention of "plasma".